# Правописание на табличке

Tags: пунктуация, фразеология, лексика, грамматика

В районе Митино г. Москвы установили памятник с очень странной, на мой взгляд, надписью
*Здесь в годы ВОВ 1941-45 гг Находились штаб и командный пункт 53ей зенитной артиллерийской дивизии Московского фронта ПВО батареи, которого защищали Москву от фашистских пиратов*
1. Правильно ли написание слова Находились с прописной буквы?
2. Разве 53-ей, а не 53-й?
3. Зенитной артиллерийской дивизии, а не зенитно-артиллерийской?
4. Правильно ли поставлена запятая? Что за билибирда со знаками препинания?
5. Разве в современном русском языке воздушные пираты это не угонщики самолетов? Мне не известен ни один фашист, кроме Рудольфа Гесса, который угонял бы самолеты. Что же получается, целая дивизия в течение четырех лет  защищала небо Москвы от сидевшего в британской тюрьме Гесса? Спрашивается, а от исламских террористов - угонщиков они ничего не защищали?

Comment: у Вас *"белиберда"* специально с двумя орфографическими ошибками?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Comment: Спрашивается, а от исламских террористов - угонщиков они ничего не защищали? _______________ Не совестно?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> *Здесь в годы ВОВ 1941-45 гг Находились штаб и командный пункт 53ей зенитной артиллерийской дивизии Московского фронта ПВО батареи,
>   которого защищали Москву от фашистских пиратов*
>
> 1. Правильно ли написание слова Находились с прописной буквы?

Неправильно.

> 2. Разве 53-ей, а не 53-й?

Да, надо 53-й.

> 3. Зенитной артиллерийской дивизии, а не зенитно-артиллерийской?

Здесь Вы немного ошиблись. Официальное наименование части: ***"53-я зенитная артиллерийская дивизия"***.

[53-я зенитная артиллерийская дивизия | ru.wikipedia.org](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/53-%D1%8F_%D0%B7%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B9%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%8F)

> 4. Правильно ли поставлена запятая? Что за билибирда со знаками препинания?

Полная белиберда, согласен.

> 5. Разве в современном русском языке воздушные пираты это не угонщики самолетов?

Там нет про "воздушных". А вообще "пираты" - слово с довольно широким значением. Здесь можно говорить про стилистическую ошибку, но не семантическую, смысловую.

> Что же получается, целая дивизия в течение четырех лет защищала небо
>   Москвы

Не выдумывайте.
Нет, только с весны 1942-го до весны 43-го. До этого, как раз в самое напряженное для ПВО время, дивизия была всего лишь 251-м зенитным артиллерийским полком. В 43-м расформирована в связи с ослаблением непосредственной воздушной угрозы Москве, воссоздан 251-й полк.

Еще, кстати, меня бесит сокращение "ВОВ" в подобных случаях. Места не хватило полностью написать?

Будет личная просьба. Вы не могли бы снимок дать этого уродства? Просто тем самым 251-м ("митинским") полком командовал мой дед (о нем есть по ссылке). Вряд ли он бы обрадовался такой памяти... *По причинам ограниченной подвижности я сам там вряд ли побываю в ближайшее время.* И если можно, с привязкой на местности.

(+) ==============
С Вашего позволения даю Ваш снимок.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Здесь есть слово "воздушных", поэтому согласен, это сочетание "воздушные пираты" здесь совершенно неуместно.

Хотя **"фронт ПВО батареи"** - это вообще чудовищно.
"Кто на ком стоял?" ПВО - на батарее, а фронт - на ПВО? 
На самом деле, конечно, дивизия ПВО входила в состав Фронта, полк - в дивизию, а батарея в состав полка.

Деды довоевались, короче.

Comment: https://instagram.com/p/BFB44_BFMbK/

Comment: https://mobile.twitter.com/AllMyGear2/status/729636774432116736

Comment: Я обращался и в управу, и в газету СЗАО, и к какой-то депутатке, позировавшей перед репортерами на фоне этого памятника, и к кандидату в депутаты Гудкову.

Comment: Спасибо огромное. Адрес точный не дадите?

Comment: Вот так деды и воевали, блин

Comment: Воздушных пиратов

Comment: Москва, Пятницкое ш., д. 25

Comment: да, спасибо еще раз.

Answer (score 0):

После ПВО требуется запятая, тогда не будет фронта ПВО батареи

Comment: Если бы только это.

Comment: Дело принято к рассиотрению москомархитектурой регистрационный № МКА-20-5356/6 от 12.05.2016 , тел для уточнения исполнителя 8 495 650 11 54